# Django: showing different title on login template

Tags: django

I'm using a single View, Template, URL to show the LoginForm to our different users.

We were using the default **LoginView** that **Django 3.0** offers.

But now we've introduced an extra step: a screen with 2 buttons so users choose if they are "clientes" or "vendedores" (sellers). **Both buttons take you to the same login page**.

> We' would like to show a different message/title, even provided that
>   it is the same Login template.

I've been reading about `extra_context`, so I've tried to make a custom `LoginView` but don't understand how to show a different title on the same Login Template, according to with button is clicked.

**This is the template with the 2 buttons that lead to the same LoginForm:**

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Ingresar con tu cuenta</h2>
  <p class="lead">Selecciona qué tipo de usuario eres</p>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un cliente</a>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un vendedor</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**My Custom LoginView:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
    """
    Display the login form and handle the login action.
    """
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    authentication_form = None
    #redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = False
    extra_context = {'client': 'cliente', 'seller': 'vendedor'}
```

**loging template that should show a different title based on clicked button:**

```
{% block content %}
  {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <p{% if forloop.last %} class="mb-0"{% endif %}>{{ error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
      <h2>Ingresar</h2>
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
        {{ form.password|as_crispy_field }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView, LoginView


from core import views

app_name = "core"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ScolarteHome.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("salir/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("ingresar-cliente-vendedor/", views.ScolarteLogin.as_view(template_name='scolarte/registration/login_client_seller.html'), name="login_client_seller"),
    path("ingresar/", views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='scolarte/registration/login.html'), name="login"),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when a user is clicking on the login button, you can add extra `GET` parameter to identify if a user is a vendor or client.

```html
{% block content %}
  <h2>Ingresar con tu cuenta</h2>
  <p class="lead">Selecciona qué tipo de usuario eres</p>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}?source=client" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un cliente</a>
  <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}?source=vendor" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">Soy un vendedor</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Then in your `LoginView` you can check for that parameter and render the different message.

```py
class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
   # other fields

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        msg = {'client': 'Welcome Client', 'vendor': 'Welcome Vendor'}
        context['msg'] = msg.get(self.request.GET.get('source'), '')
        return context
```

In your login template, just use `{{ msg }}` to render the message.